# Styled components, reverse selector pattern on input elements

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components

I'm trying to follow the 'Reverse Selector' pattern detailed [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-refer-to-other-components). Both of the below are nested within a `label` tag. Clicking the label activates the input, but the conditional styling in `FakeInput` isn't applied.

Any ideas?

```
export const CheckboxInput = styled.input`
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
`;

export const FakeInput = styled.div`
  height: 2.2rem;
  width: 2.2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.8rem;

  ${CheckboxInput}:checked & {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
  }
`;
```

It's being rendered from this function:

```
renderInputRow({ key, name }) {
    const inputRow = (
        <CheckboxLabel key={key}>{name}
            <CheckboxInput type="checkbox" name={key} />
            <FakeInput className="fa fa-check" />
        </CheckboxLabel>
    );

    return inputRow;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for these being rendered inside the label tag as well?

Comment: Mostly I'm looking for what type of input this is? A text input wouldn't have a "checked" option (so would return false) and a radio input, for example, wouldn't be something you could style the background-color of.

Comment: My thought is that maybe styled-components doesn't support inputs/checkboxes? I couldn't get :hover to work on CheckboxInput but I COULD get it to work on CheckboxLabel. I'm not getting any pseudo-selector to work on CheckboxInput. Still looking through their docs, but I'm wondering if it's just not supported?

Comment: Thanks. Yea I was wondering the same, seems odd that it's not documented though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's luckily nothing wrong with our example on the site, but it's a problem with your selector here:

```
${CheckboxInput}:checked &
```

On its own this selector is totally fine and signifies "any children of CheckboxInput when it's checked", but your code contains this:

```
<CheckboxInput type="checkbox" name={key} />
<FakeInput className="fa fa-check" />
```

So you'll want to say "any sibling of CheckboxInput", which would be:

```
${CheckboxInput}:checked ~ &
```

I've quickly pasted your code into a CodeSandbox to confirm that it works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rkmNRByE4

Hope this helps :)